# Input missmatch exception

Tags: java, exception

So far I have a text file which looks like this:

```
// this is a comment, any lines that start with //
// (and blank lines) should be ignored


[ElectricTool data]
// data is rechargeable, power, timesBorrowed, onLoan, toolName, itemCode, cost, weight
true,18V,12,false,Makita BHP452RFWX,RD2001,14995,1800
etc...
```

and the following code to go through this text file:

```
public void readData()
{ try{
    FileDialog fileDialogBox = new FileDialog(myFrame, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fileDialogBox.setVisible(true);
    String fileName = fileDialogBox.getFile();
    File dataFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);      
    String lineOfText;    
    String typeOfData="";
   while(scanner.hasNext())
   {
       lineOfText = scanner.nextLine().trim();            
       ElectricTool electricTool = new ElectricTool();         
         if (lineOfText.startsWith("[ElectricTool data]")){
           typeOfData="ElectricTool";
        }        
       else if (!lineOfText.isEmpty() ){
        if (!lineOfText.startsWith("//")){
         if ( typeOfData.equals("ElectricTool")){
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(lineOfText).useDelimiter(",");
          electricTool.extractTokens(sc);
          toolList.add(electricTool);
          itemCount++;
          sc.close();
         }
       }
    }
  }
  scanner.close();
 }     
 catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
 {
    System.out.println("ERROR: File NOT Found! ");
 }
}
```

And the problematic method:

```
public void extractTokens(Scanner sc)
{
       recheargable = sc.nextBoolean();
       power = sc.next().trim();
       super.extractTokens(sc);
}
```

The recheargable is declared as a boolean:
private boolean recheargable;

It gives me the missmatch exception when it gets to the rechargeable=sc.nextBoolean(); 
Maybe the problem is in my if statements in the readData method ? I have tried to redo the if statements, but it did not worked. Any ideas how to fix the missmatch ?

Comment: what is the data type of the variable rechargable in your code?

Comment: According to the docs, Scanner.nextBoolean "throws InputMismatchException if the next token is not a valid boolean"

Comment: private boolean recheargable;
is the declaration..

Comment: It looks like you might not move on to the next line after finding the `ElectricTool`. Try printing out the line that you pass to the `extractTokens` method to be sure that you're parsing the correct line.

Comment: try to use next() and print it as system out to confirm we are searching at the right point, or write a test to confirm the error.

Comment: true,18V,12,false,Makita BHP452RFWX,RD2001,14995,1800
etc..

is printed out when I put a system print right before
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(lineOfText).useDelimiter(",");

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to verify and created the following test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("true,18V,12,false,Makita BHP452RFWX,RD2001,14995,1800").useDelimiter(",");
    if (sc.hasNext()) {
        try {
            System.out.println(sc.nextBoolean());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(sc.next());
        }
    }
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
}
```

Its working as it should, i would change the code as following to determe the problem

```
public void extractTokens(Scanner sc) {
    try {
        recheargable = sc.nextBoolean();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("troublemaker: " + sc.next());
    }
    power = sc.next().trim();
    super.extractTokens(sc);
}
```

edit #1:
according to you answer, which i can't confirm, you may want to try some more error detection. i guess your problem is at another point.

```
public void extractTokensx(Scanner sc) {
    try {
        recheargable = sc.nextBoolean();
        power = sc.next().trim();
        super.extractTokens(sc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("dumping the rest of the troubeling line: ");
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            System.err.print(sc.next() + " - ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried the suggested the result was as follows:
It went trough recheargable, a blank terminal window showed with nothing actually printed out. Afterwards it stopped at 'power' with a "NoSuchElementException"